# Multi Thread program

Tags: c#, multithreading

Basic Goal is that i have four progress bar and want to run them at once as button is pressed and i donot have to use background worker have to do by this.

```
 var t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                try
                {

                }
        });
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
```

I tried and codded

```
 for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                var t = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    for (double x = 0; x < 10000; x = x + 0.5)
                    {
                        progressVal=(int)x;
                        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(ProgressBar));
                        Thread.Sleep(2);

                    }
                });
                t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                t.Start();
            }

 private void ProgressBar(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value=progressVal;
        }
```

but cannot think of idea how to manuplate other progress bars

Comment: Use the thread pool for that to avoid paying the significant overhead of spawning new threads all the time.

Comment: Sorry, but all telepaths have day-off today. Could you please clarify your statement and what is a question here?

Comment: `...and i donot have to use background worker...` Is this homework?

Comment: A [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is far more adapted to your scenario unless there's something else you forgot to mention.

Comment: no it was discussion among friends some beilve that this is not possible so it was kind of chalange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would put the progress bars into an array:

```
var pBars = new[] { progressBar1, progressBar2, progressBar3, progressBar4 };
foreach (var pBar in pBars)
{
    new Thread(currentPBar => 
    {
        for (double x = 0; x < 10000; x = x + 0.5)
        {             
            var progress = (int)x;
            Action<ProgressBar, int> del = UpdateProgress;
            Invoke(
                del, 
                new object[] { (ProgressBar)currentPBar, progress }
            );
            Thread.Sleep(2);
        }            
    }).Start(pBar);
}
```

and the `UpdateProgress` method:

```
private void UpdateProgress(ProgressBar pBar, int progress)
{
    pBar.Value = progress;
}
```

This being said, using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is far more adapted to your scenario.

Comment: Thank you.One more Do background woeker implements something like this at backend?

Comment: @Afnan, BackgroundWorker uses threads drawn from the thread pool which are reused. You don't need to manually create and start threads. It also takes care of properly marshaling calls between the main GUI thread and the worker thread so that you don't have to manually call the `Invoke` method. It also makes your code more concise and readable.

Comment: In your code Invoke(
                UpdateProgress, 
                new object[] { (ProgressBar)currentPBar, progress }
was not working Error is The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate, params object[])' has some invalid arguments